# Buscar caminho de arquivo C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arquivo

Preciso encontrar o caminho de um arquivo *.wav* em `C#`. consigo encontrar e executar o `.wav` com o caminho completo "c:\\caminhox...", porém, preciso que a aplicação encontre o arquivo em qualquer ***diretório que ele esteja***.

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
var file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Alarm.wav"));

SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(file.ToString());            
soundPlayer.Play();
```

porém ele não consegue encontrar o ***Alarm.wav***, pergunto:

- O que está faltando?
- Existe outra forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Encontrar automaticamente? como assim

Comment: Sem ter o caminho completo, eu estava com o projeto no meu pendrive ("F:\\CAMINHO NO PEN DRIVE"), ai troquei pra um diretório na minha maquina e ele nao encontra o arquivo pq não está mais no mesmo caminho...O arquivo está na pasta do projeto, mas ele nao encontra

Comment: Se tem que informar um caminho válido para executar, adivinhar o aplicativo não consegue, se pode colocar esse arquivo junto ao executavel e pegar o caminho do executavel e passar o nome do wav!? talvez isso resolve seu problema de imediato.

Comment: é um aplicação Windows Forms?

Comment: É isso que estou tentando fazer...Sim, é WF

Comment: Se já colocou o arquivo junto com o executavel?

Comment: Sim, está na pasta **Resources**

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69966/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-dev-john).

Answer (score 0):

Se o arquivo está na mesma pasta do executável, usa assim:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Alarm.wav"));

if (file.Exists)
{
    SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(file.FullName);            
    soundPlayer.Play();
}
else
{
  //arquivo wav nao existe
}
```

Se quiser procurar o arquivo:

```
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath).GetFiles("Alarm.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

E garanta que o arquivo seja publicado ao compilar o projeto, alterando a opção `Copy to Output Directory` você pode marcar `Copy Aways` ou `Copy if newer`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O `SoundPlayer` só precisa do caminho acho que o `FileInfo` é desnecessário.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, o caminho para os arquivos sem qualquer denominação é sempre o caminho que se inicia no local executável do próprio aplicativo,exemplo:

```
C:\\...\PastaDoPrograma\Pasta\Arquivo.arq
Se eu quiser encontrar esse arquivo, simplesmente digito:
string path = "Pasta\Arquivo.arq";
if(File.Exist(path))
File.OpenRead(path);
```

E pronto.
Isto deve funcionar para qualquer lugar em que sua aplicação esteja localizada.